# error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty when I call a rest api

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have the following code where I have an html template, I upload an `xml` file, read content of the file and I need to return a string value.

```
@Transactional
@Component
@RestController
public class ImportE125Controller  {
 
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcImportE125")
    private JdbcTemplate template;    
    
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/importE125", headers="Accept=application/xml; charset=utf-8", produces = "text/plain")
    public String getE125New(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap modelMap, 
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        modelMap.addAttribute("file", file);
        String xmlString = new String (file.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("\n\nFILE: "+ xmlString);
        Document doc = convertStringToDocument(xmlString);
        //Normalize XML structure
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        
        //Parameters
        String institutionID = null;
        String institutionName = null;
           
        int total_rows_counter = 0;
        int insertions_counter = 0;
        String cases_not_inserted = null;
        
        
             
             int insert;
             try {
                 insert = template.update("INSERT INTO tblE125Details (ForeasCode, EYear, ArProtokolou)"
                    + " VALUES (?,?,?)",
                     "test", "2022", "1" );
             }
             catch (InvalidResultSetAccessException e) 
             {
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
             } 
             catch (DataAccessException e)
             {
                 throw new RuntimeException(e);
             }
             
             total_rows_counter = total_rows_counter+1;
            
             if (insert == 1) {
                     System.out.println("\nInsert Value == "+ insert);
                     insertions_counter = insertions_counter+1;
             }
             else if (insert == 0) {
                 cases_not_inserted = cases_not_inserted + "IDno: " + pINPersonInCompetentMemberState + ", ";
             }
             System.out.println("\n\nNEW\n\n");
        }
        
        
        String str = convertDocumentToString(doc);
        //return str;
        String str_response = "Response: \n" + insertions_counter + " cases added out of " +  total_rows_counter;
        
        return str_response;
    }
```

Instead of str_response string in my browser I get the following screen:
[image]

I suppose that this controller returns an xml and not a string, even though I set `public String`. In case I change the headers to "text/plain" it's not working at all. I also tried `consumes/produces` without any luck. Any help please?

**Edit:**

I suppose that this controller returns an xml and not a string, even though I set `public String`. In case I change the headers to "text/plain" it's not working at all. I also tried `consumes/produces` without any luck.

This is an example that works, but returns an xml tree.

```
String str_response = "<response><message>" + insertions_counter + " cases added out of " +  total_rows_counter+"</message></response>";
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is hitting that line (return ...). An exception was not thrown before?

Comment: @pringi Yes, I'm sure because I use many prints in my code for debugging and it reaches the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this `headers="Accept=application/xml; charset=utf-8"`, your response will have the following content type `application/xml;charset=utf-8`.

You browser is attempting to parse an non XML response (although the content type indicates that is *XML*), and therefore you receive that error.

So, your response can be a String, if it is a XML string.

If you want to return text, remove the headers or change it to

`headers="Accept=text/plain;charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: What shall I add in headers?